# NullPointerException when importing mule project to Anypoint Studio

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am trying to import a mule project into Anypoint Studio and I get this error with a failed import

```
!ENTRY org.mule.tooling.core 4 0 2022-12-20 13:00:30.899
!MESSAGE The project can't be imported.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.tooling.core.utils.CoreUtils.createDocumentationStructure(CoreUtils.java:811)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.MuleRuntime.createMuleProject(MuleRuntime.java:148)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.importing.OpenProjectAction.lambda$0(OpenProjectAction.java:101)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.MuleRuntime.runLockingProjectsRegistry(MuleRuntime.java:317)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.importing.OpenProjectAction.run(OpenProjectAction.java:98)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.importing.ProjectImportAction.runAllActions(ProjectImportAction.java:16)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.importing.ProjectImportAction.lambda$0(ProjectImportAction.java:18)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.importing.ProjectImportAction.runAllActions(ProjectImportAction.java:18)
    at org.mule.tooling.ui.wizards.MuleProjectImportJob.runInWorkspace(MuleProjectImportJob.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9w9m.png)

I am using JDK 1.8 and Maven 3.6.3. I can't find any resources online about this error. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What version of Anypoint Studio are you using? What version of Studio was used to create the project? What file are you trying to import (zip file, jar file, etc)?

Comment: And what type of import are you selecting in the import window?